# Calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Calculate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the following matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}3&-3\\0&-2\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

**My attempt:**

I have calculated the eigenvalues to be $\lambda = 3$ and $\lambda =-2$ and I have managed to get the eigen vector for $\lambda = 3$ to be \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\ \end{pmatrix}
However I get \begin{pmatrix}1\\\frac{5}{3}\\ \end{pmatrix}

but the correct answer seems to be 
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\ \end{pmatrix}
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the original matrix is the correct one?

Comment: I'm not so sure your calculation is correct. The characteristic polynomial
is $\lambda^{2}-5\lambda-2$, and the corresponding eigenvalues are
roots of this polynomial, $(5\pm\sqrt{33})/2$.

Comment: I couldn't get your eigenvalues.

Comment: I too am getting different eigenvalues. They should be -0.37228 and 5.37228 (calculated with Octave). I found the characteristic polynomial to be $\lambda^{2}-5\lambda-2$

Comment: trace is the sum of e-vals, det of A is the product of e-vals. and $1+4 \neq  -2+3$

Comment: Sorry the original matrix is incorrect, I have now put the correct matrix there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are simply the diagonal entries, so your eigenvalues $3$ and $-2$ are correct. As
$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -3 \\
0 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
3 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
= 3 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix},$$
the vector $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = 3$.

As
$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -3 \\
0 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 5/3
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\ -10/3
\end{pmatrix}
= -2 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 5/3
\end{pmatrix},$$
the vector $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5/3\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = -2$.

So, your answers are correct. Note that $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ is *not* an eigenvector of this matrix, because
$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -3 \\
0 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ -2\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is not a scalar multiple of $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.